# Show/Hide field in SharePoint O365 based on cascadeing dropdown value selection

Tags: office-365, jquery, dropdown, cascading

I am new to SharePoint forms in O365. I have a created a form which has cascading drop downs.

1) Country - A normal drop down field

2) State - A cascading drop down field linked to Country

3) City - A cascading drop down field linked to State

If the user selects a city named "XYZ" I want another field "Comments" hidden.

Using some online tutorials i learnt and executed the below code which works if its an independent drop down field. As my drop-down field "City" is linked to other drop-down this code is not working.

Any help on executing the correct code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection
        $("select[title='City Required Field']").change(function() {
           if ($("select[title='City Required Field']").val() != "XYZ")
           {
              $('nobr:contains("Comments")').closest('tr').hide();
           }
           else
           {
              $('nobr:contains("Comments")').closest('tr').show();
           }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "As my drop-down field "City" is linked to other drop-down"? Can you please add the complete code? Have you written `.change()` for City for multiple times?

Comment: Dear Ganesh, I meant the field "City" is not a stand alone. The values in this drop down field keeps varying... e.g. Firstly user selects a vlaue from "Country" drop down, based on that selection, the value in the next dropdown "State" appear (i.e. if user selects India as Country - Kar, TN, AP appears as values in State Drop down) and Based on the State selected, values in City drop down field appears. For cascading drop down i have a different script written.

Comment: You can work with PowerApps to achieve your purpose

Comment: @Srikanth: Please check if the change mehtod of "City" dropdown is being called on change of "State" dropdown. ?
Have you written the change method of State dropdown which will call the change method of City

Comment: @ Ankit. This is the code i have for cascading drop down

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../SiteAssets/HillbillyCascade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var cascadeArray = new Array();
cascadeArray.push({
parentFormField: "Country", //Display name on form of field from parent list
childList: "State", //List name of child list
childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
childFormField: "State", 
parentFieldInChildList: "County",
firstOptionText: "< Select a State >"
});

Comment: cascadeArray.push({
parentFormField: "State", //Display name on form of field from parent list
childList: "City", //List name of child list
childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
childFormField: "City", //Display name on form of the child field
parentFieldInChildList: "State", //Internal field name in Child List of the parent field
firstOptionText: "< Select a City >"
  });

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of *id* attribute of your City dropdown to call Change event.
In this case, I assumed id as *city*.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#city").change(function() {
    if(this.value=="XYZ")
    {
        $('#Comments').css('display','none');
    }
});});
```

Comment: @ Mohammed. It's not exectuing

Comment: How can you inject that JS script to SharePoint form ?

Comment: @Srikanth  I have modified the code from on change to change event which will be executable in your case.

Comment: @AIMENBOULAHIA there are various ways to inject JS in the form like SEWP or CEWP etc. can also be injected directly to the page.

Comment: and we can achieve by that, some field permission ? for example i want to display a field for a certain users or sharepoint groups !

Comment: @AIMENBOULAHIA if you explain your situation little more, I can  be able to help you out with the situation but from what I understood, I can say doing customization, you can achieve showing/hiding the fields based on permission assigned to user Role.

Comment: Can we stay in touch in linkedin ? here is my account: https://www.linkedin.com/in/aimen-boulahia/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve that using JS scripts, but I would like to share with you how to do it with PowerApps (which is really cool and even non-developers can achieve that)

Please refer to **Mr Shane Young** which i find him very professional guy, and here the link: [PowerApps Cascading Dropdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkZG2boN7jQ)
, here you will find exactly what you want and more !

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Aimen. But we dont have access to PowerApps and need to use JS